cmake - how to use non-versioned library name
A library that I need to link has a version in the filename, like libSomeLib-1.2.so
If I tell cmake to use "SomeLib-1.2" it does so but if I use "SomeLib" then the library is not found.
I would really like not to specify the version in CMakeLists.txt so that I don't have to update if the library version changes in the future.
I have tried a few variations on the theme of finding libSomeLib*.so and making a symlink. This works on the command line, but cmake treats the * as a literal character rather than "any".
I know I can write a python script to get the path to the library and make a symlink, which I will do if SO isn't able to help.
I would prefer to do this within CMakeLists.txt, it seems like it should be possible.

It should be a symlink libSomeLib.so which points to the desired library file. That way you could use string SomeLib in find_library and target_link_libraries calls.

Note, that for many libraries a suffix before the .so extension is treated as a part of the full library name. That is, would you write your C/C++ code for libBar-1.so library, you should link with that library even after libBar-2.so library has been released. In other words, libraries libBar-1.so and libBar-2.so could be incompatible; in that case your CMakeLists.txt should specify an exact library name - Bar-1 or Bar-2 - which it wants to link with.

OK the latter is I guess what I needed to know. I should not map libSomelib-1.2.so to generic libSomeLib.so, because libSomelib-1.3.so might be incompatible.  Thanks I'll stop spending time on this.

When I asked this question, the top answer was basically that I should not try to do this because the library version may not match. Fair enough. But this CMake configuration is building common code across many different platforms, and they have different versions of libSomeLib-X.Y.so, so turns out that I do need to symlink.
Well, I could take the time to go find out which version all the platform use and make a list of options for CMake to use. But instead I'm trying this. I realize globbing is passé, but it got the job done. Testing if file exists in case some platform does not have version text.
    if(NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/libSomeLib.so" file(GLOB_RECURSE SOME_LIB "${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/libSomeLib*.so")
       file(CREATE_LINK "${SOME_LIB}" ${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/libSomeLib.so" SYMBOLIC)
    endif()
    target_link_libraries(myProgram someLib)

This solution is potentially fragile, because if there is more than one match to libSomeLib*.so, then the glob will contain a ; separated list and the symbolic link will just point to that list text and be broken. But there should be only one. I have tested this change against all the platforms that share the code and all of them build correctly.
